# vue. Для отображения изменений исользую команды npm run build и serve dist. Какой другой способ?

Tags: vue.js, консоль

`vue-cli`. Для отображения исользую команды `npm run build` и `serve dist`. После каждого изменения приходиться пересобирать и перезапускать проект. Есть ли варианты более комфортной работы? Работаю в контейнере.

Спасибо!

Comment: `webpack-dev-server` использую, очень удобно. И роутер работает, и релоудится и собирается

Comment: Спасибо! Не подскажите, как его через cli запустить? Через npm-скрипты получаю ошибку - `Module not found`

Comment: да вот не работал с cli, но где-то натыкался, что можно в него воткнуть dev server как и в webpack.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, всё равно спасибо! Добавте как ответ, что бы я мог отметить :)

Comment: а что из коробки npm run watch не устраивает?

Comment: @sepgg, ну, например то, что я с ней [коробкой] не знаком :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Недавно [vue-cli обновился](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html) и стал отличным мощным инструментом, даже с WEB UI. Пожалуйста переходите на версию 3, если еще этого не сделали.

```
# режим разработки
# для yarn 
yarn serve 

# для npm
npm run serve

# режим разработки
vue serve

# веб интерфейс для управления
vue ui
```

`build` - это сборка приложения для публикации.  После отработки `yarn build` в директории `dist`  будет готовое к публикации приложение.

```
# yarn
yarn build

# npm
npm run build
```

[Как анонсировал Evan You](https://medium.com/the-vue-point/vue-cli-3-0-is-here-c42bebe28fbb) @vue/cli - это совершенно новый инструмент, который будет включать в себя всё необходимое для разработчика.

Comment: Большое спасибо!
Отличное решение - помогло!